# Appending File Path (With Spaces) to $PATH Variable Removes the Spaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following command in my **.profile** file: `PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/spenpal/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/"`.

When I start up my terminal and try `echo $PATH`, I get the following output:

```bash
> echo $PATH
[*other paths*]:/mnt/c/Users/spenpal/AppData/Local/Programs/MicrosoftVSCode/bin/
```

The spaces were removed from the file path when it was added to the $PATH variable.

However, if I run the same command manually in my terminal and print out the paths, I get this:

```bash
> PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/spenpal/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/"
> echo $PATH
[*other paths*]:/mnt/c/Users/spenpal/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/
```

Why does it work when I do it manually vs. when I have it in my **.profile** file? And how do I prevent this from happening (*as I don't want to export this path manually every time I load up the terminal*)?

**System Specs:**

- *OS*: WSL2
- *Distro*: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Can you show us your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc` (or whatever shell startup files your shell uses) by editing your question to add them as a code block?

Comment: Can you try `echo "$PATH"` to see what output it gives ?

Comment: Try to add a backslash before the lspaces in `.profile`.